# Return the substring used for parsedatetime

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to return the value of the string (substring of original string) used to generate the output from the python package `parsedatetime` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parsedatetime/).

EX: "Take out the trash on Friday at 5PM" I know the substring used is "Friday at 5PM"

```
import parsedatetime
cal = parsedatetime.Calendar()
cal.parse("Take out the trash on Friday at 5PM")
```

Comment: You could just `split` the string and test each individual word, but what if the parts are distributed, or relate so some other information, e.g. "Take out the trash _next_ Friday" or "take out the trash on the 15. [of the current month]"?

Comment: yep! considered using `split` but seems dirty, was hoping there was a way to simply return the parsed text. Even with `split` you could get to solving for `next Friday` and `15` as you test all possible expanded substrings. This would apply to `Friday at 5PM` and the like.

Comment: I think you should post a few more examples of what should and should not be parseable. For example, what about tricky stuff such as "an all days except tuesday and friday", or "five o'clock" instead of "5 PM", etc.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing a similar problem, in my case my input string is "Get all devices that were billed last month". Just wondering whether there is a method in Python that figures out "last month" as a DateTime object and converts it to 20161201.